# MaterialTable (_this.props.data is not a function)

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I'm using a MaterialTable to display a list of users on a website, but every now and then I get the above mentioned error. Maybe you have some guesses, thanks)
The problem is most likely in the "data" proportion. Although I have previously represented the products table in a similar way and it worked, but here for some reason there is a problem.

**Error:**

[image]

**File** "*DataTable.jsx*"**:**

```
import React from "react";
import MaterialTable from "material-table";
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from "@mui/material";

const DataTable = ({ columns, data, title, actions }) => {
 const defaultMaterialTheme = createTheme();
 return (
   <ThemeProvider theme={defaultMaterialTheme}>
     <MaterialTable
       columns={columns}
       data={data} //--------------This line have a problem. 
       title={title}
       actions={actions}
     />
   </ThemeProvider>
 );
};

export default DataTable;
```

**File** "*Users.jsx*"**:**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getAllUsers } from "../api";
import { setAllUserDetails } from "../context/actions/allUserAction";
import { DataTable } from "../components";
import { Avatar } from "../assets";

const DBUsers = () => {
  const allUsers = useSelector((state) => state.allUsers);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!allUsers) {
      getAllUsers().then((data) => {
        dispatch(setAllUserDetails(data));
      });
    }
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="flex items-center justify-self-center gap-4 pt-6 w-full">
      <DataTable
        columns={[
          {
            title: "Image",
            field: "photoURL",
            render: (rowData) => (
              <img
                src={rowData.photoURL ? rowData.photoURL : Avatar}
                className="w-32 h-16 object-contain rounded-md"
              />
            ),
          },
          {
            title: "Name",
            field: "displayName",
          },
          {
            title: "Email",
            field: "email",
          },
          {
            title: "Verified",
            field: "emailVerified",
            render: (rowData) => (
              <p
                className={`px-2 py-1 w-32 text-center text-primary rounded-md ${
                  rowData.emailVerified ? "bg-emerald-500" : "bg-red-500"
                }`}
              >
                {rowData.emailVerified ? "Verified" : "Not Verified"}
              </p>
            ),
          },
        ]}
        data={allUsers}  //------- OR This line have a problem
        title="List of Users"
    </div>
  );
};

export default DBUsers;
```